# odd or even number using pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, for-loop, pointers, if-statement

I have an array, the elements inside this array should be assigned randomly
then I create two more arrays one for odd and one for even numbers
using pointers I want to put the odd numbers inside the odd array, and the even numbers in the even one.
how can I assign it using pointers?

I came up with this:

```
int main()
{
    int array[10];
    int *arrayPtr = &array;

    int arrayEven[10];
    int *pEven = &arrayEven;

    int arrayOdd[10];
    int * pOdd = &arrayOdd;

    int i, j;

    for(i=0; i<10; i++)
        {

        array[i] =rand()%100 ;




        if(array[i] %2 ==0)
        {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            printf("Even number");
        }
        else
        {
            printf("%d\n", array[i]);
            printf("Odd number");

        }

    }
```

Comment: "i have an array and its pointer" Why?

Comment: Welcome to SO. You should not use `&` when taking the address of your arrays. That will evaluate to correct address but wrong type.

Comment: What have you tried to solve that part? You need to keep track how many even and odd number you already found. And BTW: Are you aware that `arr[i]` is identical to `*(arr+i)`? Might make things more readable...

Comment: Just kindly asking: Is this a school assignment or something similar?

Comment: @Gerhardh how does converting `arr[i]` to `*(arr + i)` make the code more readable?

Comment: I'm a student and it's pretty new for me so excuse my lake of info. @Bob__

Comment: @Ackdari How does array syntax make it not more readable? I wanted to point out to the OP that they can use the pointer just as an array.

Comment: Have you been asked to explicitly use pointers? This task could be easily accomplished using a couple of indices: `int i, j = 0, k = 0; for (i = 0; i < 10; ++i) { if (array[i] % 2) {arrayOdd[j] = array[i]; ++j;} else {...} ... }`. Are you supposed to write a separate function performing the split?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These declarations of pointers

```
int *arrayPtr = &array;
int *pEven = &arrayEven;
int * pOdd = &arrayOdd;
```

are incorrect. The initializers have the type `int( * )[10]` according to the declarations of the arrays as for example of the variable `array`

```
int array[10];
```

while the declared pointers has incompatible type `int *`.

What you need is declarations like this

```
int *arrayPtr = array;
```

There is no great sense to define arrays of the same size as the source array because for example the source array can have no odd or even numbers. You should deal with arrays depending on the number of odd and even numbers in the source array. If your compiler supports variable length arrays then you can use them. Or you should dynamically allocate arrays.

Here is a demonstrative program that shows how the assignment can be done using variable length arrays and pointers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

void copy_if( const int a1[], size_t n, int *a2, int *a3, int predicate( int ) )
{
    for ( const int *p = a1; p != a1 + n; ++p )
    {
        if ( predicate( *p ) )
        {
            *a2++ = *p;
        }
        else
        {
            *a3++ = *p;
        }
    }
}

size_t count_if( const int a[], size_t n, int predicate( int ) )
{
    size_t  cnt = 0;

    for ( const int *p = a; p != a + n; ++p )
    {
        if ( predicate( *p ) ) ++cnt;
    }

    return cnt;
}

int is_even( int x )
{
    return x % 2 == 0;
}

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int a1[N];

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int *p = a1; p != a1 + N; ++p )
    {
        *p = rand() % N;
    }

    for ( const int *p = a1; p != a1 + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    size_t cnt = count_if( a1, N, is_even );

    if ( cnt != 0 && cnt != N )
    {
        int a2[cnt];
        int a3[N-cnt];

        copy_if( a1, N, a2, a3, is_even );

        for ( const int *p = a2; p != a2 + cnt; ++p )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *p );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );

        for ( const int *p = a3; p != a3 + N - cnt; ++p )
        {
            printf( "%d ", *p );
        }

        putchar( '\n' );
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
6 3 3 8 3 0 5 5 3 2 
6 8 0 2 
3 3 3 5 5 3
```

If to use your straightforward approach then the program can look the following way

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main(void) 
{
    enum { N = 10 };
    int array[N];
    int *arrayPtr = array;

    srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );

    for ( int *p = arrayPtr; p != arrayPtr + N; ++p )
    {
        *p = rand() % N;
    }

    for ( const int *p = arrayPtr; p != arrayPtr + N; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    int arrayEven[10];
    int *pEven = arrayEven;

    int arrayOdd[10];   
    int *pOdd = arrayOdd;

    int *pEvenEnd = pEven;
    int *pOddEnd  = pOdd;

    for ( const int *p = array; p != arrayPtr + N; ++p )
    {
        if ( *p % 2 == 0 )
        {
            *pEvenEnd++ = *p;
        }
        else
        {
            *pOddEnd++ = *p;
        }
    }

    for ( const int *p = pEven; p != pEvenEnd; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    for ( const int *p = pOdd; p != pOddEnd; ++p )
    {
        printf( "%d ", *p );
    }

    putchar( '\n' );

    return 0;
}
```

Its output might look for example like

```
1 0 0 3 4 5 2 1 9 5 
0 0 4 2 
1 3 5 1 9 5
```

Comment: I appreciate it,  thank you. can you please explain this line 'srand( ( unsigned int )time( NULL ) );  and why did you use enum at the begining?

Comment: @TasneemAkkad I use an enumeration to assign names to "magic numbers". The call, of srand allows to generate difference sequences of random numbers.

Answer (score 0):

For it to work you need two additional coutner variables

```c
int oddCount, evenCount;
```

these need to be initialized to be 0 (i.e. how many odd/even number you have inserted so far). Then while iterating your first array you increment the respective coutner if you encounter an even/odd number. Also you can just use these variables to know where you need to put the next even/odd number in their respective array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use binary comparison since all odd finish by 1 in binary mode :

```
If( a & 1)
//Odd
Else
//Even
```